# Thermal energy and kinetic energy at macroscopic level

Tags: energy, temperature

Does increase in kinetic energy of a car increase its temperature considering it is moving in an ideal condition where there is no friction or air resistance?

If it is not increasing the temprature,then why? With reference to a static frame all the particles have also gained kinetic energy and as per the definition of thermal energy, it is concerned withe the kinetic energy of particles. So shouldn't the temperature of the car increase?

Comment: As all motion is relative you could as well ask if the ground the car passed by heated up because it is moving relative to the car's frame of reference. Neglecting any frictions, neither heats up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If it is not increasing the temperature, then why?

It does not.

The temperature of an object is due to the average kinetic energy associated with the random motion of the molecules about the center of mass of the object. It is a component of the internal energy of the material of the object (the other being the molecular potential energy). That random molecular motion with respect to its center of mass is not effected by velocity of the mass as a whole.

Look at it another way. Suppose you are sitting in a car with a cup of coffee at rest with respect to the road. Would you expect the temperature of the coffee to increase when the car starts moving?

By the way, if it did, it would violate the theory of special relativity. But that's another subject.

> I know that kinetic energy is relative but when an object is made to
> move it needs to be given some amount of kinetic energy. Why does not
> this energy contribute in temperature change? I am not getting it at
> all.

As I explained in the first paragraph, the velocity of an object as a whole (an increase in its macroscopic kinetic energy) does not contribute to temperature change (an increase in its internal kinetic energy).

That said, one way in which the macroscopic kinetic energy of an object can contribute to a temperature change of the object is if the object undergoes an inelastic collision slowing the object. Internal friction associated withe the collision can convert some of the macroscopic kinetic into an increase in the internal energy of the object, and an increase in the temperature of its materials. But this is not the same thing as saying the velocity of an object increases its temperature.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Is it that the temperature is increasing but does not seem to be apparently. As we measure the difference in temperature by keeping another body (whose temperature is known or say thermometre) in thermal contact. But keeping the second object in contact means both of the objects are moving with the same velocity and thus this kinetic energy does not make any difference in between the car and the thermometer as particles of both of these have gained approximately equal amount of average kinetic energy??

Comment: @MohammadSakibShahriar I really can't follow your logic. The theory of relativity says that all inertial frames of reference (all reference frames moving at constant velocity) are equivalent, so the laws of physics should be the same in all inertial frames. If the temperature of something depended upon the reference frame in which it is measured, one reference frame would not be equivalent to another.

Comment: Suppose we consider that the temperature is just a physical quantity which ensures the direction of flow of heat. If one of the 2 objects remaining in thermal contact is let to move all on a sudden from rest, it would gain energy(kinetic). Now we made up our mind to measure the temperature of the moving object with respect to the static one. To keep them in thermal contact the second body also should have the same velocity as the 1st body does. In this case now both the objects have same velocity.

Comment: So could it be the reason why macroscopic movement is ignored or does not affect the temperature? @Bob D

Comment: I know that kinetic energy is relative but when an object is made to move it needs to be given some amount of kinetic energy. Why does not this energy contribute in temperature change? I am not getting it at all.

Comment: @MohammadSakibShahriar See update to my answer. Maybe this is what you hand in mind.

Comment: I got it.... Basically temperature is related to that motion of particles which causes trouble to the walls of a system in case of gases or surface molecules of solid /liquid. Since macroscopic motion lets all the particles move at a same pace, the molecules at the surface don't get extra trouble for that. And macroscopic kinetic brings in change of kinetic energy of another object when collided which thermal/internal energy does not cause. Isn't it?

Comment: @MohammadSakibShahriar I think you got it.

Comment: So, is my answer now  acceptable to you?

Comment: Yes....thank you very much